# SQL Server JDBC Drivers installation on JBoss EAP 7.3

Tags: sql-server, redhat, jboss, jdbc

are the commands below correct? if no what is the correct way to install the module properly

`module add --name=com.mssql--resources=[PATH] --dependencies=javax.api,javax.transaction.api`

`/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=mssql:add(driver-name="mssql",driver-module-name="com.mssql",driver-class-name=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgot about this question but I managed to do it few days later following my post, the solution was basically just installing the JDBC driver using the JBOSS EA7.3 graphic utility, there is a part where you can install the driver and test the connection with the DB.

I don't understand exactly why the manual way didn't work because it definitely should, both my colleague who work on a different IT solution had no problem except for me.